# How can I optimize images in all subfolders keeping folder structure?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, optimization

I have a set of folders and images inside each folder. Something like below:

```
+ Folder 1
     Image1.jpg
+ Folder 2
     Image1.jpg
+ Folder 3
     Image3.jpg
....
```

I'm trying to optimize all images inside folders using "imagemin" node.js packag with this code:

```
    const imagemin = require('imagemin');
const imageminMozjpeg = require('imagemin-mozjpeg');
const imageminPngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');

imagemin(['images/**/*.{jpg,png,jpeg,JPG,JPEG,PNG}'], 'images/dist', {
    plugins: [
        imageminMozjpeg(),
        imageminPngquant({quality: '20-35'})
    ]
}).then(files => {
    console.log(files);
    //=> [{data: <Buffer 89 50 4e …>, path: 'build/images/foo.jpg'}, …]
});
```

I can use a single folder as destination. Is there a way to overwrite images or keep same folder structure?

Answer (score 1):

In fact,imagemin doesn't provide param to keep the folder structure.
By compress images one by one is a kind of solution,have a look at my sample code:

```
const imagemin = require('imagemin');
const imageminPngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');
const globby = require('globby');
const path = require('path');

// here we got each pic path
globby('png/**/*.png', { nodir: true }).then(filePaths => {
    filePaths.forEach(filePath => {
        let fileDir = path.dirname(filePath);
        doCompress(filePath, 'out/' + fileDir);
    })
});

function doCompress(srcFile, outDir) {
    imagemin([srcFile], outDir, {
        use: [
            imageminPngquant({
                quality: '80',
                speed: 4
            })]
    }).then((ret) => {
        // todo something
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What's the solution with my case? could you help?

Comment: -1 vote due to incorrect and unhelpful response. The author is not using Gulp but is using the nodejs implementation of imagemin.